# Variables in if/else statement won't work

Tags: ruby

I'm creating an interactive story, not a game. The options don't work in the `if/else`; here is the code.

```
puts "Choose (1)yes or (2)no"
choice = gets.chomp
if #{choice}==1
  puts "you chose yes"
elsif #{choice}==2
  puts "you chose no"
else
  puts "Invalid Choice"
```

I tried leaving it intro, but that just calls the else statement, and with this setup, the tic tac toe guy in front of the brackets, it always calls the first option. please help.

Comment: Where are your line breaks? Surely you're not trying to run this as a single line of code?

Comment: Im sorry, the line breaks are exactly where they should be. after (2)no" after gets.chomp. all in the right place

Comment: If they are, then you need to ensure that they appear that way in your source-code in the question. Normal line-breaks should paste correctly into a Stack Overflow edit window.

Comment: You're missing an `end` from your `if`/`elsif`/`else`.

Comment: Your whole question is gibberish. It does not make sense. What is "intro"? What is "the tic tac toe guy in front of the brackets"? Are you joking? Is this question a spam?

Comment: Tic tac toe guy is "#" I believe.

Comment: @jcm I see. Then the OP's writing is inappropriate; it is not a guy, it is a thing. But usually, they are called hash mark, or number sign. Also, there are no brackets after it. What is after it are braces.

Answer (score 5):

`if #{choice}==1` isn't how you test the value of variables. `#{}` is for string interpolation; you don't have to interpolate anything. Just use `if choice == "1"`. Note that, because you're reading a string from the console, you need to compare against `"1"`, not `1`.

```
puts "Choose (1)yes or (2)no"

choice = gets.chomp

if choice == "1"
  puts "you chose yes"
elsif choice == "2"
  puts "you chose no"
else
  puts "Invalid Choice"
end
```

Comment: (In this case `if #rest of line is a comment` .. I'm surprised there wasn't a syntax error.)

Comment: There is definitely a syntax error, assuming this is all on one line. However, I think he just somehow didn't include line breaks in his question.

Comment: yeah, sorry, that's what happened. I tried to include them but it kept giving me an error

Comment: Your solution didnt work :( It still chooses the first option

Comment: Then you've haven't reproduced my solution correctly. I assure you, it works. See update.

Comment: Your right, I must be screwing something up. thanks so much :)